# Face mask in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, mask

**Input:** face image

**Problem:** thresholded image before applying Canny to find contours but does not return face mask

**Desired output** if different face is input,it should generate a proper face mask(face area white and background white)

Tried with apple picture..works fine

```
            #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
            #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
            #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

            using namespace cv;
            using namespace std;

            int main(){
              Mat right=imread("front.jpg");
              Mat img1;
              cvtColor(right, img1, CV_RGB2GRAY);
              threshold(img1,img1,160,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY);
              Canny(img1, img1, 128, 350);
              vector< vector<Point> > contours;
              findContours(img1, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
              Mat mask = Mat::zeros(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_8UC1);
              drawContours(mask, contours, -1, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
              normalize(mask.clone(), mask, 0.0, 255.0, CV_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);

              imshow("original", right);
              imshow("thresh",img1);
              imshow("mask", mask);

              waitKey(0);
              return 0;
    }
```

Here is the image that I used

[image]

*Please ignore the first 3 comments below*

Comment: Can you detect the ear too? Or the face direction?

Comment: So you can define the eye-corner: the point in the middle of the rect (vertically) which is nearest to the ear position. Or if you know the face direction, you can define the eye-corner, the outermost position in the middle of the eye rect.

Comment: I think a more robust approach would be to threshold the inner ROI and do a simple Harris-corner detection there. It would most likely pick up the two eye corners. Of course, you will need to do some additional checks to see if that corner is towards the ear or the nose (dataset dependent).

Comment: @Steph It seems like threshold binary inverted works fine for the above image, some thing like               `threshold(img1,img1,160,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);`
 see the result here http://i.stack.imgur.com/VtB3Q.jpg , also you don't need to do canny before find contour.

Comment: yes but this threshold value does not return a good face mask for this image http://i.imgur.com/L5kapgw.jpg. I do not want to change threshold value each time I change a picture.

Comment: Hi Steph, what's the output of your findContour? If the black region is distracting the findContourMethod, try creating the mask before warpPerspective and warp it in the same way as the image is warped!

Comment: Hi there @Micka. Remember the blending function you wrote, well I want to have a separate function which will generate the face mask of aligned images and then use it in the blending function. But it's not working :/ Here is the image of the findContours for the above image http://i.imgur.com/5BaqwqJ.jpg

Comment: that findContours result looks good. You just have to 'close' it somehow and try to remove that fragment coming from the warping (the black part int he original image). Maybe I'll find some time later, but maybe not.

Comment: after alignment,the image is bound to become like that. If it was a pure black or a white blackground,I would have used m1<255/0 or m2<255/0 but it is the background which is a problem.I just need to have this mask function.I will try it thanks

Comment: in your code, there are two problems why you can't draw a filles contour: 1. the contour isn't filled because it is not continuous. there a small dot where single contour parts don't touch. If you add a cv::dilate after the canny, the face is filled correctly. The 2. problem is, that findContours can't/doesn't extract contours at the image border. that part I couldn't solve so far...

Comment: @Steph I got fine result http://i.stack.imgur.com/iUTva.jpg with same threshold for [this](http://i.imgur.com/L5kapgw.jpg) image you provided in the link.

Comment: are you sure?because I get this with the same threshold http://i.imgur.com/YKBFKLh.jpg. Does it work for any other face image?

Comment: Yes, you can check the code here http://pastebin.com/UyEb18WT

Comment: try it with this image http://i.imgur.com/vn1fcoD.png. The mask is not good :S

Comment: @Steph So your background always is of same color ?

Comment: I have a database all the pictures have same background

Comment: So why don't you set the color range of the background (that greyish color, but it has to be a range of RGB, not a single RGB, even better is HSV color space, check out HSV color segmentation) to black and all the other pixels to white.

Comment: @Micka You got a filled face by adding dilate() ?? because I added dilate() just after the canny but the face is not filled :s it's like that http://i.imgur.com/Kn2STOi.jpg

Comment: anyone has been able to find a solution?

Comment: @Steph May be you can use the method as shown [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/28634/number-extraction-from-metal-surface/#28945)

Comment: @Haris I added the part "markers=fg+bg" because it was missing in the code. I think this is the proper way of generating the mask but still there's something missing because I get this http://i.imgur.com/NMZ7FaH.jpg. :S

Comment: @Steph Just try the code I pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/2QMfCiPw) and let me know if it's working.

Comment: So it's working, and if there any issue in the code, feel free to ask me.

Comment: it's working fine on this database.But if I take a picture from my camera,it does not return a proper mask :s

Comment: Can you show that image ?

Comment: hmm it's an ugly picture of me lol but I can show you the mask that I obtained http://i.imgur.com/C02x9h1.jpg. Could it be that the image resolution?(my phone's camera is 12MP)or the noisy background?

Comment: If I use this picture http://i.imgur.com/aogWvsQ.jpg the mask is not generated properly

Comment: The problem is ,  your background should be white, and we will take the edge of foreground to create the mask then morphology, find largest contour etc...

Comment: @Haris I think you should post your answer :)

Comment: So it is working for all your image, otherwise some one can give you better solution.

Comment: :) it is working on only one background though. When I use my phone camera,it's not a good mask.

Comment: It will work on every background if there is no edge after canny.

Comment: you can post the answer then!!!:)

Comment: So you implemented your face mosaicking system.

Comment: thanks to the people of stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this below code the mask creation working perfectly for the sample image you provided in the above commants.

Here assumes, your background is of any colour with no other object.

The below code will do

- Find edge
- Strengthen the edge by [morphology](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html) operation.
- Find biggest contour in edge( always the boundary of your foreground ) and draw it by filling.

Sometimes your contour may not be closed at the bottom(no edges at bottom)  so the filling contour wont work, so for make it closed the code first find the bounding rect for biggest contour(foreground) and then draw  bottom of  rect to the edge image, then  find largest contour again will give you the proper mask image.

```
Rect R;

Mat findLargestContour(Mat thr){

vector< vector <Point> > contours; // Vector for storing contour
vector< Vec4i > hierarchy;
int largest_contour_index=0;
int largest_area=0;
Mat dst(thr.rows,thr.cols,CV_8UC1,Scalar::all(0)); //create destination image

findContours( thr, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) // iterate through each contour.
      {
       double a=contourArea( contours[i],false);  //  Find the area of contour
       if(a>largest_area){
       largest_area=a;
       largest_contour_index=i;                //Store the index of largest contour
       }
      }
drawContours( dst,contours, largest_contour_index, Scalar(255,255,255),CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy );
R= boundingRect( contours[largest_contour_index]);
return dst;

}

int main( )
{

              Mat right=imread("1.jpg");
           // blur(right,right,Size(3,3));
              Mat gray;
              cvtColor(right, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

              int borderW=10;
              //Mat ROI=gray(Rect(borderW,borderW,img1.cols-2*borderW,img1.rows-2*borderW));
              Canny(gray, gray, 30, 255);

              Size kernalSize (5,5);
              Mat element = getStructuringElement (MORPH_RECT, kernalSize, Point(1,1)  );
              morphologyEx(gray, gray, MORPH_CLOSE, element );
              imshow("canny", gray);

              Mat largestCon=findLargestContour(gray.clone());
              line(largestCon, Point(R.x,R.y+R.height), Point(R.x+R.width,R.y+R.height), Scalar(255),2,8,0);

              Mat mask=findLargestContour(largestCon.clone());

              Mat A;
              right.copyTo(A,mask);
              imshow("original", right);
              imshow("dst", A);
              imshow("mask", mask);

              waitKey(0);


  return 0;
  }
```

See some sample mask

[image]  [image]

[image]  [image]

Comment: Hi @Haris. I am having some problems understanding the part where you specify Size kernelSize upto the morphologyEx(). Why do you have to use these?

Comment: If you imshow() the image just after canny you can see that the edge of foreground is not connected somewhere, this will cause problem while finding largest contour. So for making the edge connected the morphology used, see more information [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html)

Comment: hi @Haris. I am having some problems using this code. When the images are in their original state, the masks are generated perfectly. But when I align them,their perspective changes and the mask is one like this http://i.imgur.com/sxMhyOz.jpg :S

Comment: @Steph That because you are having two background that white and black so you have to exclude black background first.

Comment: no but the original photo is this http://i.imgur.com/dYUC2BV.jpg. I badly need this mask to generate my output..if some parts of the mask has holes,it wont be good

Comment: @Steph I think you are applying prepective transformation to src and you need mask for your result, so do one thing just extract mask first and then apply perspective transform on both src and mask and use transformed mask.

Comment: And if my above assumptions are wrong, let me know .

Comment: are you there haris?i need to ask you one more thing

Comment: I have one last problem. I combined all my functions. When I run the blending function it gives me this error http://i.imgur.com/gU4PIq8.jpg. Can you help me please? I really cannot find the error

Comment: sent you on ur mail!!thanks a lot if you can debug it..its really urgent :/