# How to remove internal contours from a hand image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have an masked hand image using skin color detection, and the main outer shape is pretty complete. But how should I go about removing the internal parts? I've tried morphological closing, erosion, dilation to no avail. I also don't want to tinker with the skin color parameters.

[image]

Comment: I think this should help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716274/fill-the-holes-in-opencv

Comment: @chintogtokh See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22427550/face-mask-in-opencv)

Comment: Thanks for that. The second method is easier to implement, I guess, what with OpenCV's floodfill mask needing to be a different size from the source image.