# how to merge (stitch) 2 images without black points in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, homography, image-stitching

I have 2 images and when I stitch them, there'll be some black area in the resulting image. I'll share the images. so how can I stitch them without the black area?

I have a homography matrix and I stitch them using ROI.

But I have a search about "seamless clone" in OpenCV, but I don't yet know it'll help me.
I need advice.

I want like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZOgr.png)

https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/html/images/Mosaic/DiagramUpdateFootprints.png

Comment: dont overwrite during after warping but write to a separate image and merge afterwards, e.g. by not copying black pixels

Comment: @Micka I didn't get. I have these images. how do I merge them without black pixels?

Comment: have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315904/blending-does-not-remove-seams-in-opencv/22324790#22324790

Comment: @Micka of course, I hope it's useful

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need a blending:

pseudo code:

```
inputs: image A, image B, backgroundColorRange X
outputs: image O

for each pixel in the output image:
    if(pixel(A) == X AND pixel(B) == X) pixel(O) = X;
    else if (pixel(A != X) AND pixel(B == X) pixel(O) = pixel(A);
    else if (pixel(A == X) AND pixel(B == X) pixel(O) = pixel(B);
    else if (pixel(A != X) AND pixel(B != X) pixel(O) = 0.5*pixel(A) + 0.5*pixel(B)
```

Comment: this is not a solution. It's working really slow. and you should give me a better solution :)

Comment: create masks and use opencv's .setTo, .copyTo and .addWeighted functions to operate on the 4 different individual mask regions. The idea stays the same.

Comment: what about     blend::seamlessBlend(first, second, mask, result);